# kubernetes pull image getting error "ImagePullBackOff"

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am going to stuck with run any container/POD.

Already see all answers related to the ImagePullBackOff issue here, but can not find any related solution.

Please see below output:-

```sh
shashi@master:~$ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx

kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1 is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubad.

deployment.apps/nginx created
```

```sh
shashi@master:~$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE

default       nginx-6db489d4b7-qsqz8           0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          33s
```

```sh
shashi@master:~$ kubectl describe pods nginx-6db489d4b7-n9mmd

Name:         nginx-6db489d4b7-n9mmd

Namespace:    default

Priority:     0

Node:         client1/10.200.13.119

Start Time:   Tue, 24 Dec 2019 10:30:51 +0200

Labels:       pod-template-hash=6db489d4b7

              run=nginx

Annotations:  <none>

Status:       Pending

IP:           10.244.1.16

IPs:

  IP:           10.244.1.16

Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/nginx-6db489d4b7

Containers:

  nginx:

    Container ID:

    Image:          nginx

    Image ID:

    Port:           <none>

    Host Port:      <none>

    State:          Waiting

      Reason:       ErrImagePull

    Ready:          False

    Restart Count:  0

    Environment:    <none>

    Mounts:

      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-hpbmb (ro)

Conditions:

  Type              Status

  Initialized       True

  Ready             False

  ContainersReady   False

  PodScheduled      True

Volumes:

  default-token-hpbmb:

    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)

    SecretName:  default-token-hpbmb

    Optional:    false

QoS Class:       BestEffort

Node-Selectors:  <none>

Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s

                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s

Events:

  Type     Reason          Age                    From               Message

  ----     ------          ----                   ----               -------

  Normal   Scheduled       <unknown>              default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nginx-6db489d4b7-n9mmd to client1

  Warning  Failed          33m                    kubelet, client1   Failed to pull image "nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.1.1:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:43144->127.0.1.1:53: i/o timeout

  Normal   SandboxChanged  32m (x5 over 33m)      kubelet, client1   Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.

  Warning  Failed          32m                    kubelet, client1   Failed to pull image "nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.1.1:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:41150->127.0.1.1:53: i/o timeout

  Normal   BackOff         32m (x6 over 33m)      kubelet, client1   Back-off pulling image "nginx"

  Normal   Pulling         32m (x3 over 33m)      kubelet, client1   Pulling image "nginx"

  Warning  Failed          32m (x3 over 33m)      kubelet, client1   Error: ErrImagePull

  Warning  Failed          3m18s (x127 over 33m)  kubelet, client1   Error: ImagePullBackOff

shashi@master:~$
```

SO please suggest the way forward..

Regards,

Shashi Kant

Comment: Are you behind a proxy.  It’s a time out.  If so have you configured docker with proxy ?

Comment: `Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io` it looks you cannot reach docker repository
Please provide more information about your environment. Are you using kubeadm, did you install CNI? Are you using Minikube or On-Prem? Are you using any firewalls or proxy?

Comment: Your `kubelet`, is trying to reach your DNS, but it can't. Check if your DNS is running on `127.0.1.1:53`. Also check this communication is open.

Comment: this is definitely a network issue. SSH into the node and test DNS resolution and network connectivity.